# Odoo 10 refresh calendar after delete

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm using Odoo 10 calendar, and try to customize function delete recurrent event.
I override the unlink function of calendar. Event, and I can delete the recurrent event now. But after deleting the virtual events still shown, and I don't know how to refresh the calendar view.

I tried to return from unlink function, but nothing change:

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'reload'
}
```

Can anyone help?